# get next auto_increament value without insertion

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have a table like this

```
|   id   |   name   |
|    1   |   Alaa   |
|    2   |   Mohd   |
```

and so on.
id is auto increament value.

**if i delete the second row the table will be like this**

```
|   id   |   name   |
|    1   |   Alaa   |
```

but the auto_increament next value will be 3.

now what i need, i need to get the next auto increament value with codeigniter.
don't tell me to use

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

**THERE IS NO INSERTION**

**I NEED TO GET THE VALUE WITHOUT ANY INSERTION.**

Comment: Execute this query : `SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM tablename LIKE Auto_increment`

Comment: @Thamilan can you please write the query. it gives me an error,check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`Auto_increment`' i'm using myISAM

Comment: it should be `LIKE 'Auto_increment'`

Comment: thanks ** @Thamilan ** , it work on localhost. but on my server need to change some of privileges and that's won't be allowed for me, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can grab that from `information_schema` see example below, just replace `tablename` and `databasename` with actual values.

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'tablename' AND table_schema = 'databasename'
```

Note: Make sure your table have `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, otherwise you will get null.